# Android running su within app

Tags: android, adb, root, su, selinux

When I use adb to access my device (Android 4.4.2 straight from the manufactures with their custom rom - its not a regular device - it has built in 2D barcode scanner) it goes straight to having a # which I've read means I have root access. And if I run "id" I get the following:

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) context=u:r:adbd:s0
```

However, when I run "su" from within my app and then "id" I get the following:

```
uid=10079(u0_a79) gid=10079(u0_a79) groups=50079(all_a79) context=u:r:untrusted_app:s0n
```

So it's clearly not running as root.
Is my understanding all wrong, in believing that it should be running as root from within the app, or is there something else I need to do in order to get this working?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the code I'm currently using to run the su and id commands:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "n");
            }


            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("id");
            p.waitFor();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "n");
            }
```

One other thing I forgot to mention - I copy the app to /system/priv-app and run it from there. Still no luck.

Comment: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/implement.html

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: The manufacturer sent me the KingRoot.apk file. I've run it multiple times and once it worked and managed to give me root access. But I have to setup our other devices as well, so cleaned the device again to its new firmware and ran repeatable (so I could document the process to do on the other devices) but haven't been successful again in KingRoot working. The manufacturer is busy talking to their engineers in order to find a solution. I'll post an update once it is successful. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had a Chinese tablet with problem like that. Just re-root it (replace `su` binary). Should work.

P.S. Seeing any code would also help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Updated question with code I use to run the su and id commands. How would I go about re-rooting it? It came rooted - from the start I could access the # with adb shell. I also copied in a new copy of su to /system/bin/su and tried to run that directly, but it had same issue.

Comment: Unlock Root worked for me back then but their web site looks broken or hacked. You can just push manually new `su` binary and [SuperSU](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/stable-2016-09-01supersu-v2-78-release-t3452703) like apk into /system.

Answer (score -1):

There is an android manifest permission you can use to gain root access

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FACTORY_TEST" />
```

Your app will run as a manufacturer test application, running as the root user. Thus making the 'su' command accessible to your app.

However, I doubt that Google Play will allow you to upload in store with such permission.

Comment: Added that permission to the manifest but still no joy. Still runs as the user I mentioned in the question. I'll have to try figure out how to re-root the device and see if I can get it to work that way.

Comment: what is the output after you run exec("su")? can you show the content of variable 'output'?

Comment: Nothing. After running exec("su") there is no returned value at all.

Comment: No SecurityException or IOException either? I believe you put your code in a try-catch block.

Comment: No errors at all. Was just catching Exception but after your comment tried to catch SecurityException and IOException, but nothing. No error.

Comment: in your command prompt, what do you see when you execute this command: `adb shell su`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123644/discussion-between-user1506104-and-mudders).

Comment: try this: exec("su;id")